# Android Studio 2.1 DDMS Does not appear

Tags: android-studio

I'm getting the following message:

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *

1. adb kill-server and then adb start-server
2. Tools > Android > Enable or Disable ADB integration.
```

I tried also kill all progress in task manager.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

From what you seem to be asking, you need to do as the error shows:

I would restart Android Studio first. Then, go to:

> Tools > Android > Enable or disable ADB integration

via the menus at the top.

Comment: The problem was i had two SDK location, One was without tools/monitor.exe. My andriod studio pointer the location where i had moniter.exe. So i have deleted the useless SDK and now it works fine.

Comment: @JoJo Ah. In that case, why don't you post your own answer for this question ;)

Comment: I am newbee for Stackover flow. SO